# Mysql - join the same table's data

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table where all comments are stored. Some comments are questions, other - answers. 
So, my table looks like this:

```
id  parent_id   message is_answer   answered
1   0           2x2     0           1
2   1           4       1           0
3   0           5x9     0           0
4   1           2x9     0           0
5   1           2x8     0           1
6   5           16      1           0
```

And as a result I'd like to get this table:

```
q_id    q_message   q_answer 
1       2x2         4
3       5x9         NULL 
4       2x9         NULL
5       2x8         16
```

So, I'd like to get all questions and answers to them, if they exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing that prevents you from joining a table to itself.

```
SELECT q.id AS q_id, q.message AS q_message, a.message AS q_answer
FROM table AS q
LEFT JOIN table AS a ON a.parent_id = q.id
WHERE q.is_answer = 0;
```

Note that this does not quite give the output you said you want... because it shows all answers to the question:

```
+------+-----------+----------+
| q_id | q_message | q_answer |
+------+-----------+----------+
|    1 | 2x2       | 4        | 
|    1 | 2x2       | 2x9      | 
|    1 | 2x2       | 2x8      | 
|    3 | 5x9       | NULL     | 
|    4 | 2x9       | NULL     | 
|    5 | 2x8       | 16       | 
+------+-----------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your requested output only shows the answer "4" for question 1.  I'm not sure if that was intentional on your part--if so, you'll need some additional GROUP BY, or other logic, to filter out the answers you do not want displayed.

Answer (score 2):

not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
select   q.id as q_id,q.message as q_message ,a.message as q_answer   FROM comments q LEFT OUTER JOIN comments a ON (a.parent_id = q.id and a.is_answer=1 and q.is_answer=0)
```

I think your table design could do without the is_answer column, you could just set parent_id = NULL if its a question?

Comment: Thanks! Adding a.is_answer=1 to ON() made the trick! Without this condition the join returned only rows which have answers. Can you explain this? :)

Comment: This answer includes all of the answers in the output as questions.  Surely that's not what's intended.

Comment: I don't think it's the a.is_answer=1 that does this, its the left ------> OUTER <------- JOIN

Comment: ... and flimzy is correct, there should be an additonal q.is_answer = 0

Comment: The keyword "OUTER" makes no difference in that query (and if I'm not mistaken, in any query, as I believe that is the default).